# Survey monkey API issues

Tags: surveymonkey

I am receiving

```
status":5,"errmsg":"Internal error, please try again later."
```

when trying to create_flow . It works perfect until I add

```
send : True
```

Then I receive the generic error message.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That error designates an issue on their end, not an issue with your input. Contact api-support@surveymonkey.com.